# Check the value of a key in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So, i have this dictionary:

```
days_per_month = {"01": 31, "02": 28,
                "03": 31, "04": 30,
                "05": 31, "06": 30,
                "07": 31, "08": 31,
                "09": 30, "10": 31,
                "11": 30, "12": 31}
```

And this function:

```
def add_months(month):
"""
If needed, increment one day and check other parameters, such as months and years.

Requires:
- dmy str with a date represented as DD:MM:YY.
Ensures: str with the updated date represented as DD:MM:YY.
"""
if month == 2:
    day = get_days(dmy)
    if check_year(year) == "True":
        if day > 29:
            month += 1
            day = 1
    else:
        if day > 28:
            month += 1
            day = 1
if days_per_month[month] = 31:
    day = get_days(dmy)
    if day > 31:
        month += 1
        day = 1
if days_per_month[month] = 30:
    day = get_days(dmy)
    if day > 30:
        month += 1
        day = 1
return month
```

Function get_days:

```
def get_days(dmy):
"""Get the number of days from a DD:MM:YY date representation.

Requires: dmy str with a date represented as DD:MM:YY.
Ensures: int with the number of days
"""
return int(dmy.split(':')[0])
```

Function check_year:

```
def check_year(year):
"""
Checks if the current year is a leap year or not.

Requires: year str with the year.
Ensures: 'True' if year is leap year; 'False' if year isn't a leap year.
"""
return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
```

Here is what I'm trying to do: I have a previous function where I increment x minutes to a certain time, let's call it y. Imagine that y = "23:56" and x = "5", 23:56 + 5 = 24:01. So, I have another function that increments one day on the date when this happens.
Now I'm trying to finish my function that changes THE MONTH. For example:
y = 23:56 and x = 5, == 24:01. However the previous date was 31/12, and now it is 32/12: I incremented a day with my previous function, but now I have to also change the month with my function add_months. So, I check my days_per_month dictionary and try to find the month(the key in the dictionary)'s value, so I can have the max number of days of that month. I think that's how I'm supposed to do it, but I keep getting this error:

```
if days_per_month[month] = 31:
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
if days_per_month[month] = 30:
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What am I doing wrong?

Obs1 - python 3.2
Obs2 - if you have any suggestion to improve any of my functions, please tell me!

Comment: You use `==` for comparison, `=` is for assignment. So `if days[month] == 31:` Also be aware about the difference in types, e.g. `5` is an `int`, whereas `"5"` is a `str`

Comment: Also, any reason not to use the built-in [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) facilities?

Comment: Im just not familiar with the built-in datetime, however I'll definitely take a look!

Comment: Or `arrow` library

Answer (score 0):

your basic problem is that you try to assign a value and not to compare it. use
`if days_per_month[month] ==  31:` instead of `if days_per_month[month] = 31:`

However i would suggest using datetime like this:

```
from datetime import *
a=datetime(2017,2,28,23,56,00)
b=a+timedelta(minutes=5)
```

what I do is initialize `a` with the Date `28.02.2017 23:56:00` and then add 5 minutes to this datetime and get the Date `01.03.2017 00:01:00` in `b`